# VB.net What does the Of() keyword do for declarations of non-generic non-collection classes?

Tags: vb.net

I am looking at the following class declaration in VB.net code:

```
Public Class ClassB(Of ClassA)
```

ClassB is not a collection of ClassA.

What does the (Of ClassA) do?

Comment: Its how you declare generics.  Read up on generics for VB.NET.

Comment: [**Generic types in Visual Basic - MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Of-Keyword is part of the class declaration in general and it is not related to lists. This is a declaration of a so called generic class.

Consider the following class:

```
Public Class ClassA(Of T)

    Private _someField As T

    Public Property SomeProperty As T
        Get
            Return Me._someField
        End Get
        Set(value As T)
            Me._someField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function DoSomeThing() As Type
        Return GetType(T)
    End Function

End Class
```

This class is taking the type parameter `T`. This parameter can be referenced throughout the whole class and enables it to work with any type you provide later on in your application when instantiating the class which could look like this:

```
Dim instance1 As New ClassA(Of Integer)
Dim instance2 As New ClassA(Of DataTable)
```

In case of `instance1` ClassA is working with the type `Integer` whereas `instance2` is the same class but working with a `DataTable`.

For example this code

```
Sub Main()
    Dim instance1 As New ClassA(Of Integer)
    Dim instance2 As New ClassA(Of DataTable)

    Console.WriteLine("instance1: {0}", instance1.DoSomeThing())
    Console.WriteLine("instance2: {0}", instance2.DoSomeThing())
End Sub
```

Will produce this output

```
instance1: System.Int32
instance2: System.Data.DataTable
```

Furthermore, since SomeProperty is using the type parameter as well you can assign an `Integer` value to it on `instance1` and a `DataTable` instance on `instance2`:

```
instance1.SomeProperty = 42
instance2.SomeProperty = new DataTable()
```

I recommend to read this article as a starting point to dive deeper into the topic of generics in VB.NET
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx